# IP Address of a server's website url in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ip-address

I would like to take a url and find it's IP Address using Javascript code.

Comment: JS does not have such capability. You have to make a request to some external service/server-side script, which will perform nslookup request.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/dns.html#dns.resolve

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is only possible with an external service. Some kind of DNS API. I Googled 'DNS Javascript', try that. This may help you http://www.fileformat.info/tool/rest/dns-json.htm